# upload Image on Mysql Server In Android My code Get an Error i am use Volly?

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

These my PHP Script Very well work check using postman upload photo successfully 
But Problem is not Working on site code check my code its working efficient 
postman outman working find in thse case android why not proper send data on serger if you guise are help they my work verywell done please please help it

```
require_once "connection.php";


$upload_path = 'upload/';
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/shopping/'.$upload_path;

$responce = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
    {
            global $connect;    

            $name = $_POST['name'];

            $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

            $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.'. $extension;

            $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension;    

            try{

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);

                $query = "INSERT INTO image(url,name) VALUES('$file_url','$name');";

                mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                {
                    $responce['error'] = false;
                    $responce['url'] = $file_url;
                    $responce['name'] = $name;
                }

            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $responce['error'] = false;
                $responce['message']=$e->getMessage();
            }
        //mysqli_close($connect);
    }
        else
        {
                $responce['error'] = true;
                $responce['message'] = 'please choose file';
        }
    echo json_encode($responce);
}

function getFileName()
 {

    global $connect;

    $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM image";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,$sql));

    if($result['id'] == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return ++$result['id'];
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
 }
```

?>
Php Code

These is My Android code please help me to solve these problem

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView imageAdd;
EditText name;
Button select,upload;
private Uri FilePath;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.0.103/shopping/file_upload.php";

private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 2210;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2310;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageAdd = findViewById(R.id.imageAdd);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    select = findViewById(R.id.select);
    upload = findViewById(R.id.upload);
    select.setOnClickListener(this);
    upload.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == upload){
        uploadImage();
    }

    if (v == select){
        ShowFileChooser();
    }
}




//Open Dialog For Choose Images

private void ShowFileChooser(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}

//Showing Result in  ImageView

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        FilePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),FilePath);
            imageAdd.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


} //over these method




private void uploadImage() {

    final String NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString(response), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("url",convertBitmapToString(bitmap));
            params.put("name",NAME);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //compress to which format you want.
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String imageStr = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 1);
    return imageStr;
}
```

Comment: I am using retrofit to upload image, if interested I can share code snippet

Comment: no sir thank you i want help for using volly library

Comment: can you post your php script ?

Comment: check again @Faiz Mir

Answer (score 0):

you are using Base64 formate to upload which is not efficient way Case encoded Base64 string's length increase more than original one . You can upload image both Base64 way and Multi part way .I prefer multi-part process .

I think below snap-net code gonna help you.
Create 
 **VolleyMultipartRequest.class**

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
private final String twoHyphens = "--";
private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

/**
 * Default constructor with predefined header and post method.
 *
 * @param url           request destination
 * @param headers       predefined custom header
 * @param listener      on success achieved 200 code from request
 * @param errorListener on error http or library timeout
 */
public VolleyMultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                              Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                              Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    this.mHeaders = headers;
}

/**
 * Constructor with option method and default header configuration.
 *
 * @param method        method for now accept POST and GET only
 * @param url           request destination
 * @param listener      on success event handler
 * @param errorListener on error event handler
 */
public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                              Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                              Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    try {
        // populate text payload
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
        }

        // populate data byte payload
        Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
        if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
            dataParse(dos, data);
        }

        // close multipart form data after text and file data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Custom method handle data payload.
 *
 * @return Map data part label with data byte
 * @throws AuthFailureError
 */
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        return Response.success(
                response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}

/**
 * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param params           string inputs collection
 * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
    }
}

/**
 * Parse data into data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
 * @param data             loop through data
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
}

/**
 * Write string data into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param parameterName    name of input
 * @param parameterValue   value of input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}

/**
 * Write data file into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
 * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
 * @param inputName        name of data input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
            inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
    if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
    }
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}

/**
 * Simple data container use for passing byte file
 */
public class DataPart {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;
    private String type;

    /**
     * Default data part
     */
    public DataPart() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with data.
     *
     * @param name label of data
     * @param data byte data
     */
    public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
        fileName = name;
        content = data;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with mime data type.
     *
     * @param name     label of data
     * @param data     byte data
     * @param mimeType mime data like "image/jpeg"
     */
    public DataPart(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) {
        fileName = name;
        content = data;
        type = mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * Getter file name.
     *
     * @return file name
     */
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter file name.
     *
     * @param fileName string file name
     */
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter content.
     *
     * @return byte file data
     */
    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * Setter content.
     *
     * @param content byte file data
     */
    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     * Getter mime type.
     *
     * @return mime type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Setter mime type.
     *
     * @param type mime type
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
}
```

You can implement in activity or fragment like this

```
private void saveDoctorProfile(final String doctorId, final String firstName, final String lastName) {
      showDialog();

    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.LIVE_API_LINK + "getDoctorProfilePersonalinfo"
            , new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            closeDialog();
            String resultResponse = new String(response.data);

            Log.d("doctor_profile_save", resultResponse);
            try {
                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(resultResponse);                  

                        AlertDialogManager.showSuccessDialog(getActivity(), "Your Personal Information saved successfully");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            closeDialog();
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            String errorMessage = "Unknown error";
            if (networkResponse == null) {
                if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Request timeout";
                } else if (error.getClass().equals(NoConnectionError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Failed to connect server";
                }
            } else {
                String result = new String(networkResponse.data);
                try {
                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    String message = response.getString("message");

                    Log.e("Error Status", status);
                    Log.e("Error Message", message);

                    if (networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {
                        errorMessage = "Resource not found";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Please login again";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Check your inputs";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
                        errorMessage = message + " Something is getting wrong";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("Error", errorMessage);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("dri_drid", doctorId);
            params.put("first_name", firstName);
            params.put("last_name", lastName);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
            // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView

            params.put("image", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getActivity(), ivPatientProfile.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));

            return params;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);

}
```